# Create page does not get styles and does not send parameters to database in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, create-view

I used Asp.netMVC and created a view but CreateView page does not get styles and does not send parameters to the database but EditView and DeleteView work.

View Code
Iadded CkEditors code under the csHtmls code

```
@model My_E_Shop.Models.Pages

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create" + Server.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model).ToString());
}    

<h2>Create@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model)</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Pages", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PageID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreateDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PageSee)


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageTitle, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PageTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PageTitle)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ShortDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShortDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShortDescription)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageText, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PageText)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PageText)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("imgUp")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageName)
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group" id="buttons">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#PageText').ckeditor();
        });
    </script>

}
```

Controller Code

```
    [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PageID,PageTitle,ShortDescription,PageText")]         
Pages pages, HttpPostedFileBase imgUp)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (imgUp != null)
                {
                    if (CheckContentImage.IsImage(imgUp))
                    {
                        pages.ImageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + 
Path.GetExtension
                            (imgUp.FileName);
                    imgUp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/PageImages/" + pages.ImageName));

                }
                }
                pages.PageSee = 0;
                pages.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.Pages.Add(pages);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(pages);
        }
```

Comment: What was the problem you can't get `PageText` value?

Comment: yes,In CreateView(Mode) page text and Image does not save into database but in EditView and DeleteView Works.

Comment: Please add one attributes in your action `[ValidationInput(false)]`.

Comment: The problem with send parameters(textbox value) Binding in line 3 into the Control code. I deleted Page ID in line 3 and it fixed.

Comment: You need to include `imgUp` in your actions parameters similar you have mentioned in `Bind(Include = "PageID,PageTitle,ShortDescription,PageText,imgUp")]         
Pages pages, HttpPostedFileBase imgUp)`

Answer (score 0):

Please check in chrome browsers developer tool all required CSS are loaded or not under **source** section

Comment: How to check can i check it?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a ViewModel class or modify your `Pages` class by adding `HttpPostedFileBase`:

```
public class Pages
{
    public string PageTitle{ get; set; }

    // ... other fields here ...

    public HttpPostedFileBase imgUp { get; set; }
}
```

And, in the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Pages pages)
{
    // ... 

    if (pages.imgUp != null)
    {
       // ... your code here
    }

    // the rest of code
}
```

However, if you prefer not adding `HttpPostedFileBase` to the model class,
you may try to **handle submit via Ajax**. For instance:

```
var formData = new FormData();    
formData.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
  url: '/Pages/Create',
  data: formData ,
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
```

For more explanation, you're encouraged to read my answer on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58354204/4687359

Hope this helped ... :)

---

Finally, if you were to upload multiple files, modify the model class accordingly:

```
public List<HttpPostedFileBase> imgUp { get; set; }
```

more clarification here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21677152/4687359